# HTTP Status 404 - / Tomcat8 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, tomcat, http-status-code-404

Подскажите пожалуйста. поставил `tomcat8` на `ubuntu 16.04`. Загрузил проект в папку `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT`. Перезагрузил. при попытке зайти на сайт пишет -

```
HTTP Status 404 - /

type Status report

message /

description The requested resource is not available
```

почему так? что я делаю не так?

Comment: Не так задаёте вопросы. Что в проекте? Зачем грузите его в ROOT? Что в логах?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev проект - сайт. что был доступ по прямой ссылке - `http://mysite.com/`, вместо - `http://mysite/com/site/`.